# How do i make my code interactive? (leaflet & Shiny R)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am relatively new to R and programming and this website has helped me so far. However, i can't find a solution to make my code interactive? could anyone teach me or point me to the direction to where i can solve my issue?

I want to make my code below interactive but do not know how

```
library(shiny)  
library(leaflet)

basemaps <- c("Esri.WorldImagery", "Stamen.Terrain", "OpenTopoMap", "Stamen.Watercolor")
```

ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
    titlePanel("Where do you want to go today?"),
    
    numericInput("longitude","(Enter a Longitude)",
                 value = 174.8, min = -180, max = 180, step = 0.1),
    
    numericInput("latitude", "(Enter a Latitude)",
                 value = -36.9, min = -90, max = 90, step = 0.05),
    
    sliderInput("zoom_level", "(Enter a zoom level)",
                value = 11, min = 3, max = 18, step = 1),
    
    selectInput("basemap", "(Select a basemap)", 
                choices = basemaps, selected = "Esri.WorldImagery"),
    
    leafletOutput("m")
)
```

server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$m <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()%>%
      setView(lng = 31.13767, lat = 29.97515, zoom = 7)%>%
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery")})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)  # Run app
```

Basically, i can run the map but when it comes to updating the map (lon,lat,zoom), it does not update. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reference your inputs within your map code:

```
  output$m <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()%>%
      setView(lng = input$longitude, 
              lat = input$latitude, 
              zoom = input$zoom_level)%>%
      addProviderTiles(input$basemap)})
```